# bijective function $h:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow A\cup B$ from bijective functions $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow A$, $g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow B$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $A,B\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and let $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow A$, $g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow B$ be bijective functions. What are ways to construct a bijective function

$$h:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow A\cup B.$$

Note that $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary subsets of the natural numbers, not necessarily disjoint. (I have this question from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/844788/prove-that-a-function-is-bijective/) but the one answer has no comments).

Comment: The answer in the question you linked to is correct up to a minor detail/possible typo.